# Actionscript get values of controls in multiple HGroup

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a flex mobile app which based upon a list of questions generates a set of controls depending on what kind of response is required, this is the input form.

The structure is

```
Group
-----Hgroup
-----------Question1, CheckBox, TextInput
-----Hgroup
-----------Question2, CheckBox, TextInput
-----Hgroup
-----------Question3, CheckBox, TextInput
-----Hgroup
-----------Question4, CheckBox, TextInput
end group
```

How do I loop through the group in Actionscript, into the HGroup and return the value of, in this example, the checkbox and textInput?

I have numerous example of how to determine the control type in the container, just not how to retrieve the values.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Wouldn't it be much faster to directly address the controls instead of looping through the group elements with the need to cast every control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To loop and type check use:

```
for (var i:int; i < hGroup.numElements; i++) {
    var child:DisplayObject = hGroup.getElementAt(i);

    if (child is TextInput) {
        var textInput:TextInput = child as TextInput;
        // do your stuff
    }
    else if (child is CheckBox) {
        var checkBox:CheckBox = child as CheckBox;
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Max. Just what I was after.